# if/else in php script not working on ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm working on a website with heavy **Ajax**, and I'm using **codeigniter** for building it.
I've got a form with post method, and this form is being posted using ajax request which call a function with **if/else statement**, like this:

```
    if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {
        $data['phase'] = 'translating';
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $data['phase'] = 'waiting_approve';
    }
```

The if/else statement check which button is being clicked, and it works 100% after posting the data of the form in the usual way, **but never works when posting it using ajax request.**
My ajax request:

```
    $('#workspace-content').delegate('form#article', 'submit', function(){
    var that = $('form#article'),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

        data = that.serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: type,
            url : url,
            data : data,
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(data){
                $('#header-search-field').append(data.msg).delay(3000).fadeOut(500, function(){
                    var that = $(this);
                    that.html('').fadeIn();
                });
            }
        });

    return false;
});
```

Any suggestion or solution?!!

---

The HTML form:

```
<button id="save-article" type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-info btn-xs pull-left">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span>
</button>
<input name="title" type="text" value="<?php echo $work->title;?>" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="" />
<textarea row="10" name="article" class="form-control" id="article" placeholder=""><?php echo $work->article;?></textarea>
<button id="submit-article" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Send</button>
<input name="slug" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $work->slug;?>" />
```

Comment: I don't usually work with jQuery, but you could try debugging it with `var_dump($_POST);` and possibly trying `var_dump($_REQUEST);` just so you can see what's going on.

Comment: Can you share your HTML form?

Comment: What's the data being sent in the request?  Seems like that would be relevant...

Comment: I edited the question and added the html form, hope it's gona be helpful.

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($_POST);` in the controller ?

Comment: Make sure that the `type` is `POST` not `GET`. By  the way, in CodeIgniter, use `&get_instance()->input->post()` instead of `$_POST`.

Comment: the output of `var_dump()` when I clicked the save button, is: `array (size=4)
  'save' => string '' (length=0)
  'title' => string 'ROS, the Robot Operating System, Is Growing Faster Than Ever, Celebrates 8 Years' (length=80)
  'article' => string '<p>،<br><strong></strong><em></em></p><p> </p><ul><li><em></em></li><li> </li><li><em>sda</em></li><li><em></em></li></ul>' (length=125)
  'slug' => string 'ros-robot-operating-system-celebrates-8-years' (length=45)`

Comment: I tried first, the same problem :\ @DamUnderscore

Comment: Do you use cookies in your system? If no, then let me know. I can suggest you an efficient method: [Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)

Comment: Unfortunately, yes I'm using it. @DamUnderscore

Comment: `that.serialize` doesn't include the button that the user clicked on to submit the form.

Comment: Waith a sec, in the above comment, you gave me the `var_dump()` of what? `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit a form normally, the button that you used to submit it will be included in the POST data. But when you submit with AJAX, and use `that.serialize()`, the POST data just includes the input fields -- the submit button isn't included. You need to attach your submit code to the buttons, so you can add the appropriate values to the data.

```
$('#workspace-content').on('click', 'form#article .btn', function(){
    var that = $(this).closest("form"),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = that.serialize();
    data += '&' + this.name + '=1';

    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url : url,
        data : data,
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function(data){
            $('#header-search-field').append(data.msg).delay(3000).fadeOut(500, function(){
                var that = $(this);
                that.html('').fadeIn();
            });
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I tried this also:
`that.find('[name]').each(function(name, value){
    var thisInput = $(this);
    name = thisInput.attr('name');
    value = thisInput.val();

    data[name] = value;
   });`
but there's the 2 buttons' names with no values :\ . any other suggestions?

Comment: Buttons don't have a value, I took that out of my answer. They just have a name.

Comment: `data[name] = value` won't work, because `data` is a string, not an array.

Comment: @Barmar Buttons can/should have values and it's quite good practice to attach a value to a button, especially if there are multiple buttons with same type and name, but different values.

Comment: True, but in his form his buttons don't have values, he's just distinguishing them by name.

Comment: @MAZux I'm not sure why `this.name` isn't working for you. `this` should be the button that you clicked on, so `this.name` should add its name to `data`.

Comment: @MAzux You have `&=undefined` because there is no input value attribute I suppose. Yes, inputs can live like that, value is manually added, but it matters for javascript. This `value=""` (blank, right, before post) will make `undefined` to dissapear I believe...

Comment: @Spooky Since he doesn't care about the value of the buttons, just which button was used, I changed my code to `this.name + "=1"`

Comment: @Barmar I tried to do this: `var clicked = $(this);` and `clicked.name + "=1"`, but the console shows me that `&undefined=1`, I don't know what's going on.

Comment: `.name` is for DOM elements, `clicked` is a jQuery object. You need to use `clicked.attr('name')`